# The height of an image within a CSS Grid layout

Tags: html, css

The size of Figure 1 is: 300px * 300px, and the size of Figure 2 is: 600px * 300px, how to solve the problem of inconsistent height of the two images. I think there is a problem with `gap:20px`, the second image takes up the width of a gap.

***Please run code snippet and view in full page.***

```css
.c3-section-grid-image {

      }
      .c3-grid-image-wrapper {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
          gap: 20px;
      }
      .c3-grid-image-wrapper .grid-item {
          position: relative;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
      }
      .c3-grid-image-wrapper .grid-item img {
          display: block;
          width: 100%;
          height: auto;
      }
      .c3-grid-image-wrapper .grid-item .grid-text {
          padding: 10px 0;
      }
      .c3-grid-image-wrapper .grid-item .text-title {
          font-size: 1.4em;
          font-weight: bold;
      }
      .c3-grid-image-wrapper .grid-item .text-desc {
          font-size: 1em;
      }
      .c3-grid-image-wrapper.text-layout-inside .grid-text {
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          padding: 16px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="c3-section-grid-image"
     style="margin: 10px 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
  <div class="c3-grid-image-wrapper text-layout-inside">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/xingshang/image/upload/v1656153419/decteamstore/220625/d9fo1r5fdlfk7jkxuf9k.jpg">
      <div class="grid-text" style="text-align:center;">
        <div class="text-title">IPhone-1</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item" style="grid-column: span 2 / auto;">
      <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/xingshang/image/upload/v1656153439/decteamstore/220625/amgv1kkbehftmb9wgwv9.jpg">
      <div class="grid-text" style="text-align:center;">
        <div class="text-title">IPhone-2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `flex-direction: column`, it caused a slight change in the dimensions of the first picture, so with it removed, everything should be fine and the height of both images are the same now.

```css
.c3-section-grid-image {

      }
      .c3-grid-image-wrapper {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
          grid-gap: 20px;
      }
      .c3-grid-image-wrapper .grid-item {
          position: relative;
          display: flex;
          
      }
      .c3-grid-image-wrapper .grid-item img {
          display: block;
          width: 100%;
          height: auto;
      }
      .c3-grid-image-wrapper .grid-item .grid-text {
          padding: 10px 0;
      }
      .c3-grid-image-wrapper .grid-item .text-title {
          font-size: 1.4em;
          font-weight: bold;
      }
      .c3-grid-image-wrapper .grid-item .text-desc {
          font-size: 1em;
      }
      .c3-grid-image-wrapper.text-layout-inside .grid-text {
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          padding: 16px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="c3-section-grid-image"
     style="margin: 10px 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
  <div class="c3-grid-image-wrapper text-layout-inside">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/xingshang/image/upload/v1656153419/decteamstore/220625/d9fo1r5fdlfk7jkxuf9k.jpg">
      <div class="grid-text" style="text-align:center;">
        <div class="text-title">IPhone-1</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item" style="grid-column: span 2 / auto;">
      <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/xingshang/image/upload/v1656153439/decteamstore/220625/amgv1kkbehftmb9wgwv9.jpg">
      <div class="grid-text" style="text-align:center;">
        <div class="text-title">IPhone-2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you can also remove the `gap: 20px` in your code, but of course, this would result in no grid gap.

Hope I helped. (:

Comment: Why it won't work when i remove `display: flex;`. The text content may be above or below the image depending on the settings, so flex-direction is required.

Comment: Ok, then I suggest just manually scaling or setting the size of the image... because I do not think that anything else can solve it.